# Use PHP to schedule a Cron Job

Tags: php, cron

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors','1'); 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include_once 'dbConnect.php';

    $startdate = trim($_POST['startdate']);
    $enddate = trim($_POST['enddate']);


    if (connect()){
        global $conn;       

        $query="SELECT electionNo FROM election ORDER BY electionNo DESC LIMIT 1";
        $details = $conn->query($query);

        while ($rows = $details->fetch_assoc())
            $election = $rows['electionNo'];

        $election=$election+1;

        $liststart= explode("T",$startdate);            
        $listend= explode("T",$enddate);    

        $start=$liststart[0]." ".$liststart[1];
        $end=$listend[0]." ".$listend[1];

        $year = substr($listend[0],0,4);

        $insertquery = "INSERT INTO election(electionNo,year,startTime,endtime) VALUES('$election','$year','$start','$end')";

        $insert = $conn->query($insertquery);
        if ($insert)
            echo 'Registered Successfully';     
        else
            echo 'No good';     
    }               
?>
```

I want to pass `$start` to a *Cron Job* to schedule the job. For example, if `$start = '2018-03-20 12:00:00'`, the *Cron Job* should be as follows:

> 00 12 20 03 * php /home/Dropbox/WebServer/paramGen.php

Which means `paramGen.php` has to be run at 12:00 on 2018-03-20.

Is this possible and if so, how do I pass `$start` to the *cron job*?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create cron job using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php)

Comment: @godot I believe my question is different from the one you suggested.

Comment: I know this won't help you with your current problem but I'd suggest to have ONE script run every minute that handles your jobs "internally"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to construct the cron command :

```
$start = '2018-03-20 12:00:00';
  $date=strtotime($start);
  $str= date('i',$date)." ".date('H',$date)." ".date('d',$date)." ".date('m',$date)." \* php /home/Dropbox/WebServer/paramGen.php";
```

then

```
exec("echo $str >> cronfile")
```

hope this helps

Comment: Important, before you test my command make sure to look at the update, it contains `>>` appending symbol, instead of overriding symbol `>`

Comment: `$str` gives the correct echo. However, what is inserted in the `cronfile` is completely different: `00 12 20 03 BlankVote.class BlankVote.java..` That is, it is listing all the files in the `WebServer` directory

Comment: @Mag, I think you need to escape the asterisks `*` as in the updated answer

Comment: I'm sorry, I am new to this. Can you tell me what commands to use to run `cronfile` as a cron job?

Comment: in fact cronfile here is not to be used literally, you must replace it with the path to your cron file followed by the name of your cronfile , which is usually at `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/crotabfile`, if you haven't created any cronjobs at all look for the documentation of your linux distribution, for the PHP part look at my answer, if you have question about how to create a cron job consider asking a question in  askubuntu.com, or unix.stackexchange.com, good luck.